# SAP Webi - Evaluate record for multiple conditions

Tags: report, webi

Using webi 4.2:

Each record contains

[image: webi1]

I've created a variable, Category, using if conditions, but it only evaluates the record once. For example, ID 24 is identified as only New when it should be identified as both New and Termed.

I need to identify each ID as to whether the state was newly added during 2022 and also whether the state was termed in 2022 (Category). The resulting table would look like:

[image: webi2]

Then for each state, I need to count the number of categories and format as follows:

[image: webi3]

I've created a variable, Category, using if conditions, but it only evaluates the record once. For example, ID 24 is identified as only New when it should be identified as both New and Termed.

```
=If [EffDate] >='1/1/2022' And [EffDate]<='12/31/2022' Then "New"  ElseIf [ExpDte] >='1/1/2022' And [ExpDte]<='12/31/2022' Then "Termed" Else "NA"
```

Any help in figuring this out would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for one ID to be two things so I am going to take a bit of different path. I will instead just two flag variables (0 or 1); one if and ID is "New" and the other if it is "Termed".

To get a dataset I could work with I did the following...

1. Typed your sample data into Excel
2. Copied and pasted it into https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm
3. Copied and pasted those results into a free-hand SQL query

Here is a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gJo3JgsX) with that SQL statement. I had to   explicitly convert **EffDte** and **ExpDte** to dates so I could actually do date comparisons with them. If you can provide SQL in a dbfiddle (or even posting it in your question if it isn't too long) that can be dropped into a free-hand SQL query  that is really helpful to those that might answer.

Anyway, here is my table with your data.

[image]

I created two variable based on your data ranges where "1" is true and "0" is false.

```
Var Is New=Sum(If( [EffDte] >='1/1/2022' And [EffDte]<='12/31/2022'; 1; 0))

Var Is Termed=Sum(If([ExpDte] >='1/1/2022' And [ExpDte]<='12/31/2022'; 1; 0))
```

[image]

I would not have needed to Sum them at this stage, but I will for the next and it doesn't hurt here so I do so at this stage.

Now I need a crosstab to start putting this together. I put **State** as the column header. I had to add an extra row beneath the last row of crosstab so that we have two rows since we do not have an actual **Category** variable. It should look like this...

[image]

Next add a "Category" column header and "New" and "Termed" row headers so your table looks like this...

[image]

Finally, you just dropped the Var Is New and Var Is Termed in the appropriate row and WebI does the rest.

[image]